# How to zip, unzip files in Objective-C (arm64 support)

Tags: ios, objective-c, zip, unzip, bzip2

I am looking for a way to zip and unzip files on iOS with arm64 support. Is there already a ready-to-use way for zip and unzipping files with arm64 support? (Best if there is also a way to integrate 7zip, bzip2, gzip, rar)

I am using SSZipArchive now, but it isn't working:

```
#import "SSZipArchive.h"

NSArray *nameWithoutExtention = [[[[self files] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] lastPathComponent] componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
NSString *fileName = [nameWithoutExtention objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *destPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", self.directory, fileName];
[fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:destPath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];
[SSZipArchive unzipFileAtPath:[[self files] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] toDestination:destPath];
```

Comment: Why would it matter? If they are open source, you can compile them yourself for 64 bit.

Comment: But when I add https://github.com/dive/ALZipArchive I get a lot error messages, that i cant fix, so I thought there already must be a fixed project/ Library

Comment: I use GTMNSData+zlib.  It's compiled for everything I have asked it to.

Comment: What are some of the errors?

Comment: Why dont you use zlib and you can make static lib , or just add all the .c files too your project

Comment: I just found SSZipArchive, it looks stabile, but sadly it isn't working right, the file isn't unziped right.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the [official SSZipArchive Objective-C example](https://github.com/ZipArchive/ZipArchive/blob/master/ObjectiveCExample/ObjectiveCExample/ViewController.m) (works on iOS11 which is pure arm64).

To zip:

```
NSString *sampleDataPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle].bundleURL
                            URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Sample Data"
                            isDirectory:YES].path;
NSString *zipPath = [self tempZipPath];
BOOL success = [SSZipArchive createZipFileAtPath:zipPath
                         withContentsOfDirectory:sampleDataPath];
```

To unzip:

```
NSString *unzipPath = [self tempUnzipPath];
BOOL success = [SSZipArchive unzipFileAtPath:zipPath
                               toDestination:unzipPath];
```

Where `tempZipPath` and `tempUnzipPath` were declared as:

```
- (NSString *)tempZipPath {
  NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/\%@.zip",
                    NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0],
                    [NSUUID UUID].UUIDString];
  return path;
}

- (NSString *)tempUnzipPath {
  NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/\%@",
                    NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0],
                    [NSUUID UUID].UUIDString];
  NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
  NSError *error = nil;
  [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtURL:url
                           withIntermediateDirectories:YES
                                            attributes:nil
                                                 error:&error];
  if (error) {
    return nil;
  }
  return url.path;
}
```